# Django ManyToManyField Error "No Foreign Key" via Through Relationship

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.7 and I am leveraging the through relationships for the first time.  First and foremost, I want to ensure that this is configured correctly; in the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on ManyToManyField advanced relationship modeling, there is reference from Group to Person, and not the other way, so I assume a 1-way relationship from Organization to Person is sufficient.

Here is my question:

When adding a new Organization, I would like the ability to create a new Person and enter their attributes from the same screen at the same time; currently I am limited to selecting from existing Person objects.

How is this possible?

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
     email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)

class Organization(models.Model):
     root_domain = models.CharField(max_length=256)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
     current_employees = models.ManyToManyField(
          Person,
          through='Employment',
          related_name='employees'
          )

class Employment(models.Model):
     person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
     organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
     date_start = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     date_end = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Organization, Person    

class EmployeeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Organization.current_employees.through
    extra = 1

class OrganizationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = (
        'name',
        'investors',
        'description',
        'root_domain',
        )
    list_filter = (
        'updated',
        'entity_type',
        'hq_state',
        'hq_country',
        )
    inlines = [EmployeeInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add related names to employment model too?

```
class Employment(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="Rperson")
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name="Rorg")
```